# Get cover photo newMeRequest()

Tags: android, facebook

Am new to FacebookSDK and I wanted to know whether I can retrieve my cover photo using `newMeRequest()`?

I know it's possible by using `Request` constructor and passing `Bundle`. Is it possible by using newMeRequest?

Help appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Please check my library: https://github.com/antonkrasov/AndroidSocialNetworks

With help of it, you can easily retrive SocialPerson, and get avatarUrl from it.

Something like:

```
mSocialNetworkManager.getFacebookSocialNetwork()
            .requestCurrentPerson(new DemoOnRequestSocialPersonCompleteListener());

private class DemoOnRequestSocialPersonCompleteListener implements OnRequestSocialPersonCompleteListener {
    @Override
    public void onRequestSocialPersonSuccess(int socialNetworkID, SocialPerson socialPerson) {

         // socialPerson.avatarURL is what you need

    }

    @Override
    public void onError(int socialNetworkID, String requestID, String errorMessage, Object data) {
        hideProgress();
        handleError(errorMessage);
    }
}
```